# How to upload json file to Google Drive in Google Colab?

Tags: json, keras, google-colaboratory

I am training a model in Google Colab and storing it in `json` format. I want to upload this trained model to my drive in the colab itself.

I am currently doing:

```
model_json = model.to_json()

with open("trainedModel.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("trainedModel.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
print("This file ran till end.\nNow uploading to drive:")

uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id':'#id_no'}],'title': 'trainedModel.json'}) 
uploaded.SetContentFile('trainedModel.json')
uploaded.Upload()

uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id': '#id_no''}],'title': 'trainedModel.h5'}) 
uploaded.SetContentFile('trainedModel.h5')
uploaded.Upload()
```

But this gives me:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets.json'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the authorization code given to the notebook that grants it permission expires after a few minutes/hours.

This problem got resolved by requesting the authorization code again. That is inserting

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

after saving the model file and before uploading it to the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the file browser browser or Drive FUSE instead. Both are radically simpler than using the Drive API directly.

File browser upload:

[image]

Drive FUSE:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

([Details](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA))

Comment: I am doing `from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)` and `!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)` before the above code. I want to upload the file which is made during the execution of the code...